# R package choroplethr says use zip_choroplethr instead of zip_map, but function not available

Tags: r, choroplethr

I did `install.packages("choroplethr")`, followed by `library(choroplethr)`. I want to find out how to do a zip code choropleth, so I start typing in RStudio, 
"`?choroplethr::zip`..." The only function that RStudio finds is `zip_map`. I go to its help file and see the following documentation:

> This function is deprecated as of choroplethr version 3.0.0. Please
>   use ?zip_choropleth instead. The last version of choroplethr in which
>   this function worked was version 2.1.1, which can be downloaded from
>   CRAN here:
>   http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/index.html

Okay, I guess I'll find out about this `zip_choroplethr` function then.

```
?choroplethr::zip_choroplethr
# No documentation for ‘zip_choroplethr’ in specified packages and libraries:
# you could try ‘??zip_choroplethr’
```

Wut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for using choroplethr.

zip_map is, indeed, deprecated. It used scatterplots, which wasn't the best way to visualize zip codes, especially because they are so small.

Within choroplethr, Zip code choropleths are managed by a new, separate package: choroplethrZip. You can see the installation instructions and documentation [here](https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethrZip).

CRAN rejected choroplethrZip due to the size of the map, which is why it is in separate package and on github.